# What's a reliable way to check which files and directories have recently taken up disk space of the root partition?

Tags: linux, debian, kde, disk-usage, storage

I already tried things like `sudo du -csh *` (in the root dir), `sudo find /usr/lib/ -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -10` `sudo du -a / --exclude=/media --exclude=/home | sort -n -r | head -n 100` and similar commands. I'm looking for something that is about *recent* disk space use and that works *reliably* (even in my use-case).

The problem with these is that because there is "No space left on device" I can't run them - if I free up some disk space (for example by running bleachbit or removing large unnecessary packages or deleting some files in /tmp/)  it doesn't take long until that space is taken up as well. [I already moved /var/lib/docker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625135/why-do-i-have-var-lib-docker-and-getting-accessed-even-though-i-dont-have-do) which was several GBs in size which were shown to be freed up afterwards - now something must have taken up these GBs worth of disk space.

The second problem is that when I run these commands when I have some free disk space I currently couldn't easily identify which of the files and directories are new and unnecessary.
The largest directory seems to be /usr/share.

However, `sudo du -csh /usr/share/* | grep "G"` only displays that it's 7GB which shouldn't be too large. An earlier output of `sudo du -ah / --exclude=/media --exclude=/proc --exclude=/home | sort -n -r | head -n 100` which I stored to another partition only shows files of 1 MB sizes (including in /usr/share/).

---

**Is there a good way to nicely and quickly output a list of the largest files and directories which have recently been added, maybe even including processes responsible for that?** It would also be useful if one was able to specify another /tmp/ directory for running the command if that's possible. I'm using Debian10/KDE.

A simple and reliable way to list what's recently been taking up disk space would be very handy here.

**Update**: I was able to show recently modified files in the root directory that are larger than a specified filesize with the preinstalled **KFind**. I can't exclude directories with it and I can't start veracrypt to unmount a partition because I only get the message "veracrypt is already running". However, I was still able to find the problematic file:

*it was /proc/pid/task/pid/fd which was an open instance of the konsole with only one command running where aborting that command did not free up the disk space - I had to close the konsole window with all its tabs and subsequently had several GBs worth of free disk space again.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the above simple commands to get the last modified files and directories  using `mtime` :

```
# Get files/dirs modified during the last 15 days and then desc  sort with disk usage and print the first 10 lines
find / -mtime -15  | xargs -I {} du -sm {} | sort -rn | head -10
# Get files/dirs modified during the last 60 minutes and then desc sort with disk usage and print the first 10 lines
find / -mmin -60 | xargs -I {} du -sm {} | sort -rn | head -10
# Get files/dirs modified between 2020-12-18 and 2020-12-19 then desc sort with disk usage  and print the first 10 lines
find / -newermt 2020-12-18 ! -newermt 2020-12-19 | xargs -I {} du -sm {} | sort -rn | head -10
```

If your system is able to store the creation time ; then you can use `crtime` instead.

Check first on any file that `crtime` is set :

```
## Output should be different than - sign
stat -c '%w' <file>
```

Then you can use the same find command with `B` option `Birth Time` :

```
# Get files/dirs **created** between 2020-12-18 and 2020-12-19 then desc  sort with disk usage and print the first 10 lines
find / -newerBt 2020-12-18 ! -newerBt 2020-12-19 | xargs -I {} du -sm {} | sort -rn | head -10
```

If your filesystem handles `Birth Time` but you are not seeing it in stat command, you can check directly on the device level that is holding the files by :

```
# Getting the inode number
ls -i <file>
# Then get crtime 
debugfs -R 'stat <inode_no>' <device>
```

There is a python package that was written by @PascalVKooten [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408272/get-file-creation-time-with-python-on-linux) called `crtime` that you can use to get the creation time, I don't know if it's recursive (not tested) but it will give you an output like the following :

```
1552938281  /home/pascal/crtime/.gitignore
1552938285  /home/pascal/crtime/README.md
1552938282  /home/pascal/crtime/crtime
1552938288  /home/pascal/crtime/deploy.py
```

Then you can sort timestamps by desc order and convert them to date time if you want :

```
sudo crtime ./ | awk '{print$1}' | sort -rn |  xargs -I {} date -d @{}

Mon Mar 18 20:44:48 +01 2019
Mon Mar 18 20:44:45 +01 2019
Mon Mar 18 20:44:42 +01 2019
Mon Mar 18 20:44:41 +01 2019
```

Finally, to get the last processes that edited certain files or directories, you can use `auditctl` and setup a custom rule then query the logs with `ausearch`.

You can also use `inotify-tools` to do the same but I think it can seriously affect the memory usage if you do it for the whole root filesystem.

`Lsof` cannot be used because it concerns the current opened files and not the recent ones.

Also if you are able to use a third party tool, then think about using `ncdu`
with enabling extended information mode to sort by extra attribute like `mtime` then you can export the output to a file.